# My pong game not working with Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012, and easeljs

Tags: javascript, windows-8, easeljs

I am trying to get a simple Pong game going from Chris Bowen's MSDN blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbowen/archive/2012/09/19/using-createjs-in-your-javascript-based-windows-store-game.aspx

I am at his "Setting the Stage" section and theoretically I should be able to launch the app and have the ball and paddles in my Pong game, but instead when I run the codes in Visual Studio 2012, I get the below error:

```
Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line 42, column 87 in ms-appx://521809a7-6594-45ba-a60e-bb529eac1299/js/createjs/easeljs-0.5.0.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: TypeMismatchError
The program '[3756] WWAHost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Unfortunately the easeljs-0.5.0.min.js file is minimized so it is ugly, but I believe this is the one causing the problem at the mentioned line and column:

```
var d=this._ctx.createPattern(a,b||"");
```

Below is my default.js file:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            // your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            // Restore application state here.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(init()));
    }
};

var ball, paddle1, paddle2;
var stage;

function init() {
    stage = new createjs.Stage("gameCanvas");

    ball = new createjs.Shape();
    ball.graphics.beginFill("White");
    ball.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
    ball.x = 400;
    ball.y = 300;

    paddle1 = new createjs.Shape();
    paddle1.graphics.beginBitmapFill("White");
    paddle1.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 100);
    paddle1.x = 20;
    paddle1.y = 300;

    paddle2 = new createjs.Shape();
    paddle2.graphics.beginBitmapFill("White");
    paddle2.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 100);
    paddle2.x = 760;
    paddle2.y = paddle1.y;

    stage.addChild(ball, paddle1, paddle2);
    stage.update();
}

app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
    // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
    // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
    // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
    // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
    // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
    // args.setPromise().
};

app.start();
})();
```

My simple default.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Pong</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

<!-- Pong references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
<script src="js/createjs/easeljs-0.5.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the paddle code to `beginBitmapFill` versus `beginFill`, but are still passing a color name into the call, and that's causing the type mismatch,

[Per the documentation](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/Graphics.html#method_beginBitmapFill),

> ```
> Graphics beginBitmapFill ( image , repetition )  
>    Begins a pattern fill using the specified image. This ends the current subpath. 
>
> Parameters:
>    image <object>        The Image, Canvas, or Video object to use as the pattern. 
>    repetition <String>   Optional. Indicates whether to repeat the image in the fill area. 
>                          One of "repeat", "repeat-x", "repeat-y", or "no-repeat". 
>                          Defaults to "repeat". 
>
> Returns:  
>    Graphics The Graphics instance the method is called on (useful for chaining calls.)
> ```

Comment: Doh!  Thanks for looking through my code in detail.  I picked the wrong autocompletion in Visual Studio. :(  This fixed the problem.

Comment: the joys of dynamically typed languages :(